# How to test compress rate of rsync with two big local files?

Tags: rsync

I want to test if rsync will work to sync some huge DVD images containing installers in order too see if what speedup can I obtain from using rsync, if any.

I would like to run the test locally, how can I convince rsync to just evaluate how much data would be required in order to sync the two files?

PS. I am fully aware that I *should* try to sync small and uncompressed files, but this is outside the question in this case.

Comment: Maybe you could ssh to yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
rsync -avz --log-file="/Users/username/rsync.log" /home/test /home/testlocation
```

then check log file for size and speed